# Node.js express application get any link

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing an `express` app in `Node.js` and want to know if it is possible to get any link that the user goes to. So on my localhost, if I do this:

```
localhost:8000/test
```

It will return `"test"`.

This is my current setup:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"files")));

// The rest of my server code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you are trying to do is possible.

Here is an example continuing with your code structure:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"files")));

app.get('/:link', function(req, res) {
    var link = req.params.link; // This variable holds the accessed link
    console.log("The link is: " + link);
}
```